# Two graphics cards usage

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hdmi, graphics

I'm building a new PC and my motherboard has an onboard Intel graphics card on it. I am also getting an Nvidia graphics card. The Nvidia card has 2 HDMI ports on it and the motherboard has 1 HDMI port on it. So is it possible for me to get 3 monitors, hook 2 up to the Nvidia card and 1 up to the motherboard and have a triple screen setup?

Comment: What model is the graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, but you'd probably be better off getting a graphics card that can drive three monitors. To some extent, when you use multiple graphics cards, you get the worst of each.

Comment: so how exactly will that play out for me if I connected 1 monitor to the onboard and 2 to the nvidia? Any serious lags, bugs, glitches?

Comment: Would you mind being a little more specific in how you get worse?

Comment: You'd get some of the worst features of each. For example, because the onboard video requires shared memory, you'd lose a bunch of memory for that. And your CPU would have to do the extra work to communicate with both GPUs, each of which has somewhat different requirements placed on it. Software couldn't optimize itself to the GPU because there is no "the GPU".

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but then you'd be dealing with two separate configurations to set up (the onboard one and the Nvidia one). It would be easier to get a 3-output video card. Plus, using an aftermarket video card usually offers a greater range of configurations and an increased overclocking capacity (if you're into that sort of thing).

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible to use 3. Once you install a video card the graphics is rerouted to that card and nothing is sent to your computer's onboard card, I wouldn't know how to change settings to make both work together or if that's even possible, but I know that they don't work together by default. So you will only be able to use 2 monitors unless you install 2 video cards that are exactly the same, which would allow you to use 4 monitors.